# How to add ngx_http_ssl_module to the compiled version of nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, google-pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I have a problem with setting ssl on my server. I have configured nginx with the modpagespeed (compiled version from https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source)

`nginx: [emerg] the "ssl" parameter requires ngx_http_ssl_module in /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

I need to add the ngx_http_ssl_module module, but I don't know how to do it without damage the rest of the configuration that I already have.